# Split FullName Where has null values (db2 sql)

Tags: sql, database, split, db2

I have full name that contains blank or null value and cause an error when I split into first name,lastname.

**here is the error:**
ERROR [22011] [IBM][DB2/AIX64] The statement was not executed because a numeric argument of a scalar function is out of range.

**here is my original code:**

```
UPPER(right(AGENT_NM, (char_length (AGENT_NM) - position( ' ', AGENT_NM))))|| ', ' || UPPER(left(AGENT_NM, position( ' ', AGENT_NM) - 1)) AS AGENT_NAME,
```

**here is what I have tried:**

1-

```
CASE when REGEXP_COUNT(AGENT_NM,',')> 0 then left (AGENT_NM, position( ' ', AGENT_NM) - 1) END AS FNAME,
```

2-

```
CASE when(AGENT_NM= ' ') then Null Else left (AGENT_NM, position( '
> ', AGENT_NM) - 1) END AS FNAME,
```

***However it returns blank.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate a space onto the end of your name first:

```
SELECT
  TRIM(UPPER(RIGHT(AGENT_NMs, char_length (AGENT_NMs) - position( ' ', AGENT_NMs))))|| 
    ', ' || 
    TRIM(UPPER(left(AGENT_NMs, position( ' ', AGENT_NMs) - 1))) 
  AS AGENT_NAME
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      a.*,
      COALESCE(agent_nm, '')||' ' as agent_nms
    FROM
     yourtable a
  ) x
```

Here we use coalesce to ensure the name is not null, and we then add a space on as something for the position function to find

The top bit is just your code tweaked to refer to the new name agent_nms and add an extra trim command for removing any extraneous spaces. It did look like it had one too many brackets in by the way

Answer (score -2):

```
name=str(input("your name here"))
split_name=name.split(" ")
```